# Resize image in a script using Imagemagick

Tags: bash, shell-script, imagemagick

I'd like to create a bash script to resize images up to 800px keeping proportion...

My code doesn't work in bash, but it works using `identify` with a single image :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./**/public/uploads/*.*; do
  width = $(identify -format "%w" ${file})
  if [ width > 800 ]
  then
    echo $file // resize image
  fi
done
exit 0;
```

Issue : I get `Permission denied` on line 3

I tried the solution given in one of the answers below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/public/uploads/*.*; do 
  width=$(identify -format "%w" "${file}")
  if [ "$width" -gt 800 ]
  then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
exit 0;
```

And I now get this error message:

```
identify.im6: Image corrupted   ./folder/public/uploads/ffe92053ca8c61835aa5bc47371fd3e4.jpg @ error/gif.c/PingGIFImage/952.
./images.sh: line 6: width: command not   found
./images.sh: line 7: [integer expression expected
```

Comment: When asking about scripts that "don't work", you need to tell us i) what you expect to happen; ii) what actually happens iii) the exact error you receive. That said, I'm guessing you forgot to add `shopt globstar` to your script to enable the `**`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two obvious issues in your script. First, the `**` is provided by the `globstar` option which isn't on by default. You've probably activated it in your interactive shell, but you need to do so for the script as well.

Then, you'e not actually comparing `$width` but the string `width`. The `$` is needed in `[ ]`.

The last issue is that some of the files you are running this on are either corrupted, or not images. In any case, the `identify` command fails on them so `$width` is empty. A simple solution would be to test whether `$width` is empty (`-z "$width"`) and only compare if it is not (`! -z "$width"`):

Try this instead:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/public/uploads/*.*; do 
  width=$(identify -format "%w" "${file}")
  if [[ ! -z "$width" && "$width" -gt 800 ]]
  then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem (or, at least, one of the problems) is that you're saying

```
width = $(identify -format "%w" "${file}")
```

You need to eliminate the spaces before and after the `=`, like this:

```
width=$(identify -format "%w" "${file}")
```